# Set mailer "from" value to smth arbitrary in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, smtp, email-headers

My email address from which I deliver messages is **noreply@domain.com**, when I send message with:

```
mail(:from=>'noreply@domain.com', :to=>"somebody@gmail.com", :subject=>"Welcome!")
```

**from** field in Gmail shows **noreply**, so I have tried using following:

```
mail(:from=>'domain', :to=>"somebody@gmail.com", :subject=>"Welcome!", :return_path=>"noreply@domain.com", :reply_to=>"noreplay@domain.com")
```

above returns:

```
554 Message refused.
```

All I want is that **from** field was saying something like "MyDomain" or whatever. So how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using

```
:from=>'MyDomain <noreply@domain.com>'
```

If this doesn't work then add a header with key 'FROM' and value in following format:

```
From_Name <from_email>
```